# How to set separate (or multiple) template paths for pages and partials in Mustache with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mustache

I set the template path:

```
class Mustache
  self.template_path = 'templates/pages'
end
```

This works fine.

But, I want to store the partials in a separate folder: `templates/partials`.

A mustache template looks like:

```
Hello {{ name }}
Your info: {{> info }
```

`info.mustache` is a partial.

The info partial has no class, so I can't set `self.template_path`.

So, how to set a template path for a partial, or have multiple template paths?

```
self.template_path = 'templates'
self.template_path = 'templates/'
self.template_path = 'templates/*'
self.template_path = 'templates/**'
self.template_path = [ 'templates/pages', 'templates/partials' ]
```

did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  If you look at this file you see that only the template path can be set. Partials end up using the same path during rendering.

https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/blob/master/lib/mustache/settings.rb

However, if you name your partial {{>partials/info}}, it will look for info.mustache inside  your template path(templates/partials/info.mustache).

You can also override the partial method from mustache.rb like this:

```
class Fubar < Mustache
  def partial(name)
    partial_name = "partials/#{name}"
    super(partial_name)
  end
end
```

In the end a partial is no different than any other template. The pathing that you want is just for organizational purposes.

Another user brought up a good point that mustache is now maintained. There was a point in time where the original contributor had stopped supporting it.  I'm glad someone else had picked up the project.

Comment: >>"Mustache for Ruby is not maintained anymore" .....    Sounds pretty active repository to me.